# react native fetching data from API depend on dynamic id

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, axios

i am new in react native in my home screen i manage to fetch data from API using redux and axios now what i want

when i press on image it take me to EventInfo screen and display info depend on dynamic id in Postman the APIrequest POST and take this {"id":"5680"}
to display the info

[image from api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hg77b.jpg)

```
    _onLImagePressed() {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('eventInfo');

    }

  _renderListItem = ({ item }) => {
    Moment.locale('en');
    var dt = item.date;
    return (   <View style= {{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row',marginBottom: 3}}>
        <TouchableOpacity  onPress={this._onLImagePressed.bind(this)}>
        <Image
          style={{width: 80, height: 80,margin: 5}}
          source={{uri: item.imageUrl}}
        />

        </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', marginLeft:5}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 18, color:'green', marginBottom:15}}>
      {item.id}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 16, color:'red'}}>
        {Moment(dt).format('DDD MMM YYYY')}</Text>
      </View>

      </View>)

  }
```

Comment: So you requires that specific list item id in your next component?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to pass your id from the function which you are executing on onPress and pass your id to your navigation component

```
{ onPress() => this._onLImagePressed({item.id}) }
_onLImagePressed(id) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('eventInfo', { id: id});
}
```

and after that you can get your id in eventInfo component like this.

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.id
```

Tip:: Always bind your function in your constructor if you bind inside your render function on every rendering it will create a new instance and that will cause performance issue

Answer (score 1):

To get the corresponding details from the `'eventInfo'` route, you must also add the `id` details as part of the route.

Then in the `componentDidMount` of the `eventInfo route component`, you can get the `id` from the `route` and use `axios` to fetch the details and render dynamically.

The specific syntax would depend on the packages being used, but this could be a general idea.

Also, if by any chance, you cannot pass the id as a route param, you could also set a global value (such as a redux-store state) to the corresponding id before navigation and from the eventInfo component, read this state and fetch from api using axios inside the componentDidMount like above.